# How to make objects a percentage of the width of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, width

I'm trying to put 3 divs that fill the width of the window, and their `width` changes according to the dimensions of the window. However `javascript` seems to be giving a window width larger than it actually is causing the objects to flow out of the window causing scroll. You can see my full code here: http://jsbin.com/vifagazefu/3/edit?html,css,js,output

This is the javascript:

```
 $(window).resize( setDim());

function setDim() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth()- 3; //the 3 is for the 1px margin between the divs

  var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight() - 70;

  $(".one").innerWidth(windowWidth / 3);
  $(".two").innerWidth(windowWidth / 3);
  $(".three").innerWidth(windowWidth / 3);

  $(".one").innerHeight(windowHeight);
  $(".two").innerHeight(windowHeight);
  $(".three").innerHeight(windowHeight);
}

setDim();
```

Comment: Firstly, it should be `$(window).resize(setDim);` not `$(window).resize( setDim());`. Secondly, why not using CSS media queries? Or if js is required for any other reason, then use instead `widow.matchMedia` method

Comment: Why don't you just use percentages in the CSS? `.one, .two, .three { width: 33%; }`

Comment: I'm working on a project in which I have divs inside of another div. And i want these inner divs to be a percentage of the window not of the parent.

Comment: @A.Wolff Whats the difference between calling a function with parentheses and without them?

Comment: The body element has a margin. You can set all the elements box values(margin, padding, border) in the document to 0 to make it work. Or use percentages in CSS like @Barmar suggested.

Comment: You want here to use referenced function, so remove parentheses. Otherwise, you are using as handler the result returned by function, which here is undefined

Comment: Oh that explains a lot of the errors I have had when working on methods that require functions

Comment: @CosX How to select them all? Does "*" work with css?

Comment: @RanaMallah You can write something like this `*{margin:0;}`. That selects every element.

Comment: I have to recommend you using some of the CSS reset snippets, and you can check this one to see if it helps: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put `$(document.body).innerWidth()-3;` instead of `$(window).innerWidth()-3;` and you'll be fine. this is because the body element has margins and it's set by the browser, yes you can reset the margin of the body to 0px but why not we get more accurate and calculate the body.

here is the edited bin using the `$(document.body).innerWidth()-3;` http://jsbin.com/puqavufela/1/

and here's the edited bin using the `body {margin:0px}` http://jsbin.com/somogusugo/1/